# TreeMap In Python - Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, treemap

I have code below which simply creates a Treemap in Python. Can anyone help me in creating only all Vertical Rectangles in Treemap or Horizontal using below code sample.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify
volume = [350, 220, 170, 150, 50]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
color_list = ['#0f7216', '#b2790c', '#ffe9a3', '#f9d4d4', '#d35158', '#ea3033']
plt.rc('font', size=14)
squarify.plot(sizes=volume, label=labels, color=color_list, alpha=0.7)
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

[image: Current sample graph in Python]

**it should look like horizontal or vertical stack Bar chart. but any option to create using Treemap in Python. because i want to modify it further. Below is the proposed look.**

**Desired vertical output**
[image: Desired vertical output]

**Desired horizontal output**

[image: Desired horizontal output]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Many of us can't see linked images. Could you embed them, please? And we need to see some effort toward writing the TreeMap code. It's unlikely that someone will code it for you from scratch.

Comment: @rajah9 i don't want anyone to code from scratch
just want someone helpful to modify the above code to look like what i wanted.
there may be some matplotlib property that will do the tick but i am not able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `norm_x` and `norm_y` to specify the shape of the rectangle to fit the data into (default is a 100 x 100 square, hence the name *squarify*):

Horizontal:

```
squarify.plot(sizes=volume, norm_x=100, norm_y=10, label=labels, color=color_list, alpha=0.7)
```

Vertical:

```
squarify.plot(sizes=volume, norm_x=10, norm_y=100, label=labels, color=color_list, alpha=0.7)
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/laserson/squarify#Documentation-for-Squarify) for details.